# Function to parse psql timestamp

Tags: php, postgresql, timestamp

I display the date or the time on my website a lot and I'm thinking about writing a function to parse a PostgreSQL timestamp.

The timestamp is in the format: `Y-m-d H:i:s.u`. E.g. `2011-04-08 23:00:56.544`.

I'm thinking about something like this:

```
function parse_timestamp($timestamp, $format = 'd-m-Y')
{
    // parse the timestamp

    return $formatted_timestamp;
}
```

However I am wondering whether this can also be achieved without writing a parser for it myself (with the use of some PHP function).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function parse_timestamp($timestamp, $format = 'd-m-Y')
{
    return date($format, strtotime($timestamp));
}
```

Don't forget to set timezone before, e.g.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Or in your case, I guess `'Europe/Amsterdam'`.

You can always get PHP timestamp of this format `Y-m-d H:i:s.u` using `strtotime()`. Then, using `date()` you can export time in your own format. Both functions depend of time zone set.

Answer (score 4):

[strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) is perfectly capable of parsing that time string, then just reformat it with [date](http://php.net/date):

```
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime('2011-04-08 23:00:56.544')); // 08-04-2011
```

Answer (score 3):

For those using DateTime class:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', $yourTime);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the database isn't giving you what you want, change it. PostgreSQL can also [format dates and times](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html).

```
select to_char(timestamp '2011-03-04 07:04:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY');
04-03-2011
```

But that's risky in international contexts, like the web. Different locales expect different ordering of elements.  (Does "04-03" mean 03-April or 04-March?) This expression is easier to understand, and it uses locale-specific abbreviations for the months.

```
select to_char(timestamp '2011-03-04 07:04:00', 'DD-Mon-YYYY');
04-Mar-2011
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `strptime` function - it can parse many time formats.